# Loops for every time step on a time-dependent function coming from NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, conditional

I have a time-dependent function `a[t]`, which comes from solving various differential equations. Therefore, to obtain the different values of `a[t]` I have to evaluate it on the solutions from NDSolve: `a[t]/.solutions`.

For every value of t I want to impose the following:

```
If[a[t]<0,

  a[t]=None,
  a[t]=10]
```

However, I get neither "None" nor "10", since for some values of the time t `a[t]` will be <0 and for other values of t, it will be >0. Is there a way I can include a `For` to evaluate every possible time value of `a[t]`?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The question is not very clear. Perhaps you are looking for [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)?

Comment: Perhaps you want to define: `fun0[t_]= a[t]/. solution; fun[t_]:= If[fun0[t]<0,, None,10]`